# Максимум из двух чисел

Tags: pascal, freepascal

Я запутался с Условным оператором If then else, я ввожу

```
Program help2; 
var a,b,c:LongInt;
begin
    ReadLn(a);
    ReadLn(b);
    a:= ( b < c ); //   и тут я не понял
   If then else
```

По идее, я ввожу 1 и 2, а мне долно показать 2 наибольшее число!
Я не знаю, как вывести наибольшее число при помощи If then else.

Comment: @ChokaLatkA, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

@ChokaLatkA, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: @ChokaLatkA, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

(b < c) - это логическое выражение, у которого результат может быть либо *true*, либо *false*.
Вы же логическое выражение пытаетесь присвоить переменной целочисленного типа, что ведет к ошибке уровня компиляции - является абсурдным, одному типу данных вы пытаетесь присвоить выражение другого типа данных.

Конструкция if then else выглядит следующим образом:

```
if <услове> then
  <оператор/выражение, которые будут выполняться, если условие - истинно>
else
  <оператор/выражение, которые будут выполняться, если условие - ложно>
```

Т.е. сначала проверяется условие, если оно истинно (результат проверки = true), то выполняется оператор (блок операторов), следуемый за **then**, иначе (если условие ложно), то выполняется оператор (блок операторов), следуемый за **else**.

Например:

```
if (4 > 3) then
   writeln('4 > 3')
else
   writeln('Не может быть такого, чтобы 3 было больше 4.');
```

Проверяется условие (оно может быть необязательно простым). В примере это 4 > 3, т.к. 4 больше 3, то результат проверки условия будет true, поэтому выполнится writeln('4 > 3') и на экран будет выведено: 4 > 3.